# Mixing Guice constructor injection and Jersey @Context

Tags: jersey, guice

I'm trying to use construction injection using both Jersey-injected @Context parameters and Guice-injected parameters.

This works (pure Jersey injection):

```java
@Path("top")
public class TopLevel
{
  public TopLevel(@Context ResourceContext context)
  {
    ..
  }
}
```

This works (pure Guice injection):

```java
@Path("top")
public class TopLevel
{
  @Inject
  public TopLevel(MyService service)
  {
    ..
  }
}
```

But this does *not* work:

```java
@Path("top")
public class TopLevel
{
  @Inject
  public TopLevel(MyService service, @Context ResourceContext context)
  {
    ..
  }
}
```

because Guice does not know how to inject ResourceContext. If you look at [JerseyServletModule](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/contribs/jersey-guice/com/sun/jersey/guice/JerseyServletModule.html) you will notice it injects the following classes:

```java
WebApplication, Providers, FeaturesAndProperties, MessageBodyWorkers, ExceptionMapperContext, HttpContext, UriInfo, ExtendedUriInfo, HttpRequestContext, HttpHeaders, Request, SecurityContext and HttpResponseContext
```

but not ResourceContext. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**: I don't think I can use field injection because I need the ResourceContext to instantiate another instance field. For example:

```java
public class Foo
{
  public Foo(ResourceContext context) {}
}

public class Bar
{
  private final MyService service;
  private final ResourceContext context;
  private final Foo foo;

  @Inject
  public Bar(MyService service, @Context ResourceContext context)
  {
    this.foo = new Foo(context);
  }
}
```

If I were to instantiate ResourceContext after the constructor, I couldn't instantiate `Foo`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to inject it into an instance field using @Context. If that does not solve your problem (i.e. you really need to access it in the constructor), you can file an enhancement request at http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY and we will add it to the JerseyServletModule. The change is pretty minor.

Comment: I don't think I can inject an instance field (I've updated the question to explain why). I've filed http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-1219

Comment: Thanks. Fixed in 1.13-SNAPSHOT.